# i have a problem in my flutter App when project run in android studio

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

** flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);

I used
.
.
.

> firebase_core: ^1.7.0....I cheked in my code but there is not show any error shoud i change in my library file of firebase_core:1.24.0  ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have  encountered the same issue and i fixed by:

1. Updating the packages in pubspec.yaml file to the latest versions:

```js
firebase_core: ^2.1.1
firebase_auth: ^4.1.0
cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3
```

2. Removing the pubspec.lock file
3. Running `flutter clean`
4. And last running this command `flutter pub get`

Comment: Always update package with version number flutter demands. And also upgrade other package which depend on updated package.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are some breaking change of firebase_core_platform_interface that do not comply with semantic versioning: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9806

You need to overwrite this library:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N36N0.png)